# What's the best way to convert a react native app to native iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I wrote an app in react-native, but am not quite happy with the performance. If I had a genie, I'd ask for an exact swift or obj-c replica of the app and just continue working with that. Are there any tools that might help with that?

Comment: Don't think so, but if you're having performance issues then you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: What type of performance issues are you having? Are they animation based? PanGesture based? Those can be fixed.

Comment: For most application React Native will not be noticeable less performant than native apps. So unless you are doing some heavy CPU / GPU tasks you can probably get your application to work smoothly

Comment: We are taking a bunch of images (100s over a couple of hours) and uploading them along with other data. We are often running into OOM errors. This can definitely be a shortcoming of the implementation of our store.